Using table as reference for ranges in CASE expression
My query:
SELECT AgeBand, COUNT(LoanID) as "Number of loans"
FROM (
SELECT CASE
        WHEN (Client.Age>Age.Low_Value and Client.Age<=Age.High_Value) THEN AgeID
        END as AgeBand,
LoanID
FROM Loan, Client, Age
WHERE Loan.CustomerID = Client.CustomerID
AND Loan.PastDue_Days >= 1
GROUP BY Age)
GROUP BY AgeBand

This does not work. The Age table:



AgeID
Low_Value
High_Value




A
0
10


B
10
20


C
20
30


D
30
40


E
40
50


F
50
60


G
60
70


H
70
80


I
80
90


J
90
100


K
100
150



How can I use the Age table to reference these age ranges without having to hard-code them?
The query above returned the count for a blank row and 'A' for AgeBand. Desired result is a count of loans between each age band, based on the age band values.

Please show the content of all affected tables and also the expected result.

You need something like this:
SELECT AgeID AS AgeBand, COUNT(LoanID) AS "Number of loans"
FROM Age
LEFT JOIN Client
ON (Client.Age>Age.Low_Value and Client.Age<=Age.High_Value)
LEFT JOIN Loan
ON Client.CustomerID = Loan.CustomerID AND Loan.PastDue_Days >= 1
GROUP BY `AgeID`

Explanation:

we use the Age table as our point of departure with the intention of having exactly one record in the result set for each Age
we LEFT JOIN Client, so we intend to find all the clients of said age if they exist
the join criteria with Client is that Client.Age fits the interval of the Age
we also LEFT JOIN with Loan so we get the picture of how many loans where for the Age
the criteria of this second join is that its CustomerID matches its counterpart of the Client already found and that the PastDue_Days is strictly positive
and of course we GROUP BY AgeID to ensure that we aggregate properly, having exactly one record for each Age
in the select we get AgeID AS AgeBand and we intend to get the COUNT(LoanID) as the Number of loans, yet, if some Age groups have no Loan matches


No need for COALESCE, COUNT(LoanID) can return 0.
